# Is text-rendering allowed in @font-face declaration?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, text-rendering

I've stumbled upon a CSS file for webfont integration, in which [`text-rendering`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-rendering) property was used inside of [`@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face):

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Font Name";
  /** ... */
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
```

My IDE tells me that this is an incorrect usage, and it is according to the MDN. Is this a mistake of CSS author or is there some browser discrepancy involved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably a mistake on the author's part. `text-rendering` is a property, not an `@font-face` descriptor. Furthermore, it's a *text* property, not a *font* property. These are two distinct categories of properties.